# MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings. help command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

I am trying to make a help command for my discord bot, when i type .help it gives an error

```
 /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js:416
     if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
                                   ^
 
 RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
     at Function.verifyString (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js:416:41)
     at Function.normalizeField (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:544:19)
     at /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:565:14
     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
     at Function.normalizeFields (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:564:8)
     at MessageEmbed.addFields (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:328:42)
     at MessageEmbed.addField (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:319:17)
     at Object.execute (/app/commands/informational/help.js:12:10)
     at module.exports (/app/events/messageCreate.js:28:18)
     at Client.emit (node:events:390:28) {
   [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
 }
```

The code : https://pastebin.com/eyKhB2qs

Comment: [Discord Embed Example](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview) this should provide your answer but if not. its cause your add field is supposed to take 3 parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding a field in your embed, it takes at least three values. The first is the title of the field you are adding and the second is the value of the field. The third value is a boolean and it states whether the field is inline or not. You have only passed the title of the field and you need to pass something in as the value as well such as: `.addField('title', 'description', true)`. You can learn more about embeds in [Embeds | Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview)

Comment: still the same error with 2 more fields added

Comment: Did you repeat it for all the embeds?

Comment: i added 2 more fields for each of the embeds yes and now its giving me the error
TypeError: ReactionPages is not a function

Comment: I'm not sure about that since I have not used the `ReactionPages` module. Sorry

Comment: Are you sure that the module `reconlx` is installed in your `package.json` file?

Comment: its completely installed yes

Comment: @EmeraldCS it looks like a completely different error, you should probably [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with more details. Also, as this answer solved your original issue, you should upvote and accept it by clicking the checkmark icon.